# Listening for page reload, Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Ok, so I am interested in listening for when a specific URL is access or reloaded via a Chrome extension. How would I go about this? I am brand new to Chrome plugin development...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily using a content script. A content script is JavaScript code that is injected into a page as the user loads pages. So you'd add something like this to your manifest.json file:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches" : [
            "some_url"
        ],
        "js" : [
            "some_content_script.js"
        ]
    }
],
```

Just replace "some_url" with the URL you're looking for, and replace "some_content_script.js" with a file that contains the JavaScript code you'd like to run.

Here's a bit more info on Content Scripts, for your info:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html